# How we can add session variables so we can use them in all templates?

Tags: twig, grav

How we can add a session in `Grav` and use that in all twig templates?

To set custom sessions in `Grav` and use those globally in all twig HTML templates, we can do so by setting the session globally in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the plugin controller file
   (In my case: user-plugins-pluginName-pluginName.php)

```php
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
        'onTwigExtensions' = ['onTwigExtensions', 0]
    ];
}
 
public function onTwigExtensions() {
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/pluginName.php');
    $this-grav['twig']-twig-addExtension(new PluginNameTwigExtension());
    $this-grav['twig']-twig-addGlobal("session", $_SESSION);
}
```

Add session like this Globally and by doing this session could be used further in any of the twig templates.

2. Then, we need to set the session variable like

```php
$_SESSION['key'] = $_POST['value'];
```

3. Now we can use this session value in any twig HTML template as:

```html
{{ session.key }}
```